# How to align decimal point of table entries having units and no units

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs, siunits

I have the situation, that I have to present some metrics of many different signals. However, some metrics have units others are unitless and some are percent values. In the example the values using `\SI{99.99}{\percent}` are not aligned while the others without `\SI{99.99}{\percent}` are aligned. Is it possible to align the numbers at the decimal point? I do not want a extra column for the units.

I found a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140353/align-position-of-decimal-point-within-table-of-numbers-text-and-percentage-val), but could not adapt it to my needs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,7pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering

\sisetup{
  table-align-text-post=false, %
}

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=1.6]
 S[table-format=3.3]
 S[table-format=3.3]
}
\toprule
Measure &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Signal1} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Signal2} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Signal3} \\
\midrule
MAE       & \SI{0.250}{\volt}     & \SI{235.25}{\ampere}   & \SI{235.25}{\ohm}     \\
MAPE      & \SI{1.012}{\percent}  & \SI{10.25}{\percent}   & \SI{10.285}{\percent} \\
RMSE      & \SI{0.25}{\volt}      & \SI{235.25}{\ampere}   & \SI{235.2}{\ohm}      \\
Metric 1  & 0.000498              & 0.498                  & 232.34                \\
Metric 2  & 0.0498                & 14.498                 & 0.34                  \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `S` columns: you need to write units separetely, for example with the use of `\si{...}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,7pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htpb]
\centering
\sisetup{
    table-align-text-post=false, 
    table-space-text-post={\,\%}%
        }

\begin{tabular}{
                 l
                 S[table-format=1.6]
                 S[table-format=3.3]
                 S[table-format=3.3]
                }
    \toprule
Measure & {Signal1} & {Signal2} & {Signal3} \\
    \midrule
MAE       & 0.250 \,\si{\volt}     & 235.25 \,\si{\ampere}   & 235.25 \,\si{\ohm}       \\
MAPE      & 1.012 \,\si{\percent}  & 10.25  \,\si{\percent}  & 10.285 \,\si{\percent}   \\
RMSE      & 0.25  \,\si{\volt}     & 235.25 \,\si{\ampere}   & 235.2  \,\si{\ohm}       \\
Metric 1  & 0.000498               & 0.498                   & 232.34                   \\
Metric 2  & 0.0498                 & 14.498                  & 0.34                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You were the faster! The only difference was the thin space was inside `\si`…

Comment: @Bernard,sometimes I'm lucky, usual is opposite  ;-). Yes, `\,` can be inside `\si{...}` ...

Comment: @Bernard, thank you very much for corrections. It is never good to hurry to much. Before posting my answer I should read again, what I wrote.

Comment: I can assure you you're not the only one :-)

Answer (score 4):

I honestly wouldn't bother with aligning numbers within a given column on their decimal markers if the units are wildly incommensurable. In fact, aligning these numbers on their decimal markers might *mislead* readers into believing that the numbers share some common unit(s).

Instead, I would left-align the cell contents and thereby send a deliberate -- and hopefully unmistakable -- signal to the readers that the numbers in the column are incommensurable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,7pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l lll @{} }
\toprule
Measure & Signal1 & Signal2 & Signal3 \\
\midrule
MAE       & \SI{0.250}{\volt}     & \SI{235.25}{\ampere}   & \SI{235.25}{\ohm}     \\
MAPE      & \SI{1.012}{\percent}  & \SI{10.25}{\percent}   & \SI{10.285}{\percent} \\
RMSE      & \SI{0.25}{\volt}      & \SI{235.25}{\ampere}   & \SI{235.2}{\ohm}      \\ 
\addlinespace
Metric 1  & 0.000498              & 0.498                  & 232.34                \\
Metric 2  & 0.0498                & 14.498                 & 0.34                  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I fully agree with Mico's opinion that numbers that have no relation with one another should not be aligned at the decimal point.

There is no relationship with a measure in volts and one in amperes or ohms and there shouldn't be a visual relationship between their representation in print.

However, I'd prefer right alignment rather than left alignment, together with `\num` for the figures in the last two columns. Also some more room between the columns seems to fit better.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{0.5em}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{3}{r} @{} }
\toprule
Measure  &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Signal1} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Signal2} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{Signal3} \\
\midrule
MAE      & \SI{0.250}{\volt}    & \SI{235.25}{\ampere} & \SI{235.25}{\ohm}     \\
MAPE     & \SI{1.012}{\percent} & \SI{10.25}{\percent} & \SI{10.285}{\percent} \\
RMSE     & \SI{0.25}{\volt}     & \SI{235.25}{\ampere} & \SI{235.2}{\ohm}      \\ 
\addlinespace
Metric 1 & \num{0.000498}       & \num{0.498}          & \num{232.34}          \\
Metric 2 & \num{0.0498}         & \num{14.498}         & \num{0.34}            \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would not consider do that at all, but reconsider the table design. Without understand what are the metrics and biting my tongue to not change all decimals, maybe to some like:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cSSSS[table-format=6.9]S@{}}\toprule
% & & & {Measures}  & & \\\cmidrule{2-6}
Signal & {MAE}   & {RMSE}   & {MAPE (\%)} & {Metric 1}  & {Metric 2} \\
\cmidrule(rl){2-4}\cmidrule(rl){5-5}\cmidrule(rl){6-6}
1 (V)  & 0.25    &   0.25   &  1.012 & 0.000498  & 0.0498 \\
2 (A)  & 235.25  & 235.25   & 10.250 & 0.498     & 14.498 \\
3 (Ω)  & 235.25  & 235.20   & 10.285 & 232.34    & 0.34  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I must say I find this significantly harder to parse than the original table. How do I know that the entry in the first line, first column is in units [V], but in the last column it's units [1]?

Comment: @Emil With electricity knowledge only change a light bulb and  without know that are the metrics  (resilience? performance?)  to me is equally incomprehensible this way or rotated, but if as I guessed signal 1 is the voltage, the signal 2 the amperage  and the signal 3 the resistance,  then units of MAE (Mean Absolute Error, i guess)  and RMSE (Root Mean Square Error, I guess) are obvious (as well as in MAPE, although I added  `(%)`  to clarify the "P" for the less skilled with the acronym).

Comment: @Emil  Note also that I placed the metrics  apart to remark that  are not V, A, or ohms, but without known more about,  is hard to me imagine if it should be obvious the lacks of units or  if it could be clarified in the header, or adding the units in the columns 2,3 and 4.